# How to synchronize EC2 instance time with local machine time?

Tags: windows, time, amazon-ec2, synchronization

I want to synchronize the time between Amazon EC2 instance (windows server 2008) and local machine (windows 7)? I heard about NTP, but not so sure about its usage for EC2 instance.

I want to synchronize the time with respect to millisecond precision.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following in both of your servers:

1. Open the command prompt as Administrator
2. Stop the W32Time service: `C:\>net stop w32time`
3. Configure the external time sources, type: `C:\> w32tm /config /syncfromflags:manual /manualpeerlist:”0.pool.ntp.org, 1.pool.ntp.org, 2.pool.ntp.org”`
4. Make your server a reliable time source for the clients. Type: `C:\>w32tm /config /reliable:yes`
5. Start the w32time service: `C:\>net start w32time`
6. The windows time service should begin synchronizing the time.
7. You can check the external NTP servers in the time configuration by typing: `C:\>w32tm /query /configuration`